# prestashop change multiple combination image

Tags: prestashop

I have developed a site on Prestashop and now I am transferring products to a new site. for each product I need to configure product combinations. among the combinations there is a choice of color and for a certain color you need to put a certain picture, here is an example of the finished result:

[image]

Now I do it manually by clicking on the pencil icon and changing the picture.

Is there any faster way to do it?

I want to find some quicker and easier way, not to sit and change the pictures in a monotonous and boring way myself